# VS C++ точки останова с проверкой std::string

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Интересует возможность использования в *Visual Studio (2017)* условных точек останова (*conditional breakpoint*) с проверкой переменной типа *std::string*.
Ниже упрощенный пример итерирования по коллекции записей; цель - попасть на итерацию с нужным id:

```
for(const std::string& itemId : itemIds)
{
    // Остановиться при itemId == "particularId"
...
}
```

Пробовал выполнить преобразования  от std::string к const char*:

> strcmp(itemId.c_str(), "particularId")==0

и наоборот

> itemId == std::string("particularId")

но не увенчалось успехом.

P.S.: Интересует именно настройка брейкпоинтов, условные проверки в коде и иные правки кода не подходят

Comment: [how to create conditional breakpoint with std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740858/how-to-create-conditional-breakpoint-with-stdstring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может не так к char* приводите? У меня вот так работает:

```
strcmp(&itemId[0], "particularId") == 0
```

Comment: Так действительно работает. Приводил методами c_str и data, но получал ошибку The bp cannot be set. This expression has side effects and will not be evaluated. С сылкой на нулевой элемент работает